# Bootstrap 3 navbar - how to style LI elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've created my own CSS to override some of the bootstrap.min.css styling.  I've managed to change things like the navbar height:

```
.navbar {height:100px;background-color:#D44043;opacity: 0.9;}
```

However I'm really struggling to find how I change things like the active state color, height of the UL (which seems stuck at 50px), UL text colors, hover colors, caret colors...

Is there a CSS reference for all of this somewhere?  I can't see it on the getbootstrap.com site.
Appreciate the advice, thank you.
NJ

Comment: i can recommend http://bootswatchr.com/ or similar tools to change the css of bootstrap. overriding styles you load before isn't the best way. Better modify the base LESS variables to achieve what you want.. its not hard really.

Comment: If you create a separate stylesheet then when you update the Bootstrap core files your changes won't be overwritten. Therefore it's better practice to override the Bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar>li>a {
 padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
 line-height: 20px;
 }
.navbar>li{
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 }
use these codes to style your navbar li customize you navbar li css codes here
.navbar>li{

 your css..
 }
.navbar>li>a{

 your css..
 }
```